# How to send value in bundled ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm working on the ReactJs project where we aren't using any API to manage data.

In the project we use Webpack to bundle React APP.

Now issue is the React APP is should be useable on any website by including the bundle.js and website will allow to give some input data and accordingly we will load the ReactAPP.

So, I'm finding the best way to send data into bundled ReactAPP so we can write our logic to load React based on provided Data.

Note: There is no chance to use API call as ReactAPP is independent to use on any website by including bundle.js

In PHP Website

## index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
const configReactApp = {
   "selector": "loadmy_react_here", //should ID
   "config": {}
};
</script>

<!--- My React APP bundled js using Webpack --->
<script src="bundled.min.js"></script>

<body>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="left-panel"></div>
      <div class="right-panel">
        <div id="loadmy_react_here">
         <!-- Load my react app here --->
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

## In React

```
ReactDOM.render(<DashboardComponent 
   myArgument = {configReactApp.config}
/>, document.getElementById(configReactApp.selector)

);
```

Comment: Setting a value on the `window` should be sufficient.

Comment: What's your question? Looks like you're already trying to have a global config variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ReactJS file src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

window.MyReactApp = {
    init: (selector, myData) => {
        selector = selector.substring(1);
        const renderComponent = (<homeComponent mydata={myData} />);
        ReactDOM.render(renderComponent, document.getElementById(selector));
    },
};
```

Now load the ReactJs App where you want to load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="load-myreactapp"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const myData = {};
    MyReactApp.init('#load-myreactapp', myData);
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome solution event its allow us to load our React App as per different need.